# Is there an idiomatic way to cut out the middle-man in a join in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

We have a Customer model, which has a lot of has_many relations, e.g. to CustomerCountry and CustomerSetting.  Often, we need to join these relations to each other; e.g. to find the settings of customers in a given country.  The normal way of expressing this would be something like

```
CustomerSetting.find :all,
                     :joins => {:customer => :customer_country},
                     :conditions => ['customer_countries.code = ?', 'us']
```

but the equivalent SQL ends up as

```
SELECT ... FROM customer_settings 
INNER JOIN customers ON customer_settings.customer_id = customers.id
INNER JOIN customer_countries ON customers.id = customer_countries.customer_id
```

when what I really want is

```
SELECT ... FROM customer_settings
INNER JOIN countries ON customer_settings.customer_id = customer_countries.customer_id
```

I can do this by explicitly setting the :joins SQL, but is there an idiomatic way to specify this join?

Comment: What associations do you have on your `CustomerSetting` class?

Comment: @William: belongs_to :customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides of finding it a bit difficult wrapping my head around the notion that you have a "country" which belongs to exactly one customer:

Why don't you just add another association in your model, so that each setting `has_many` customer_countries. That way you can go

```
CustomerSetting.find(:all, :joins => :customer_countries, :conditions => ...)
```

If, for example, you have a 1-1 relationship between a customer and her settings, you could also select through the customers:

```
class Customer
  has_one :customer_setting
  named_scope :by_country, lambda { |country| ... }
  named_scope :with_setting, :include => :custome_setting
  ...
end
```

and then

```
Customer.by_country('us').with_setting.each do |cust|
  setting = cust.customer_setting
  ...
end
```

In general, I find it much more elegant to use named scopes, not to speak of that scopes will become the default method for finding, and the current #find API will be deprecated with futures versions of Rails.

Also, don't worry too much about the performance of your queries. Only fix the things that you actually **see** perform badly. (If you really have a critical query in a high-load application, you'll probably end up with #find_by_sql. But *if it doesn't matter, don't optimize it*.

Comment: when you say each setting has_many customer_countries, I'm guessing you mean something like has_many :customer_countries, :primary_key => 'customer_id', :foreign_key => 'customer_id' ?

Comment: Sounds like what I had in mind. Never tried exactly that setup, but in theory it could work. You'd have to try it to see if it also works if there's more than one setting for a customer... again, from a Rails perspective I'd prefer the named scope solution.